# How to report file progress to clients using SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, events, signalr

I have written a component that gets and excel file and stores its data into a database. Since I wanted this class to support different environments (for example using it inside a console app) So I decided to create some events:

```
public interface IDataSeeder
{
    Task Seed(string fileName);
    event EventHandler<UserSucceedEventArgs> UserAdded;
    event EventHandler<UserErrorEventArgs> Error;
    event EventHandler<UserUpdateEventArgs> UserUpdated;
    event EventHandler<FinishDataSeederEventArgs> ProcessCompleted;
}
```

Each of this events will trigger in different places inside `Seed` method. It works like a charm in my console application.
Now I want to use this component inside my ASP.NET MVC app, for doing so I decided to use SignalR for pushing event's data to client, So I created a hub like this:

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{
    public static void UserAdded(UserSucceedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
        ctx.Clients.All.userAdded(e);
    }

    public static void Error(UserErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
        ctx.Clients.All.error(e);
    }

    public static void UserUpdated(UserUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
        ctx.Clients.All.userUpdated(e);
    }

    public static void ProcessCompleted(FinishDataSeederEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
        ctx.Clients.All.processCompleted(e);
    }
}
```

Then I created this action method for getting uploaded file and pass it to my component:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddFromExcel(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
{
    if (excelFile != null)
    {
        var fileName = Utilities.UploadFile.UploadFile.UploadCommonFile(excelFile, "users");
        _dataSeeder.UserAdded += DataSeeder_Succeed;
        _dataSeeder.Error += DataSeeder_Error;
        _dataSeeder.UserUpdated += DataSeeder_Update;
        _dataSeeder.ProcessCompleted += DataSeeder_Finish;
        await _dataSeeder.Seed(Server.MapPath($"~/Content/Files/users/{fileName}"));
        return RedirectToAction("AddFromExcel");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("List");
}

private static void DataSeeder_Finish(object sender, FinishDataSeederEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressHub.ProcessCompleted(e);
}

private static void DataSeeder_Update(object sender, UserUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressHub.UserUpdated(e);
}

private static void DataSeeder_Error(object sender, UserErrorEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressHub.Error(e);
}

private static void DataSeeder_Succeed(object sender, UserSucceedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressHub.UserAdded(e);
}
```

As you can see inside each event handler I notify the clients using my signalr hub.

All of this process is like a messaging system, but I have no idea how to implement it inside a web application. A flaw with my code is that after attaching the event handler I immediately redirect the user to another action method, I know it must be an asynchronous process but I have no idea how to make my events async.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is match the `SignalR` server calls with `JavaScript` functions that will show the results to the connected clients:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // the proxy to your hub
   var hub = $.connection.ProgressHub;

   // the function that will be called when you call
   // ctx.Clients.All.userAdded(e);
   hub.client.userAdded = function (data) {
      // show the data
      alert(data);
   };

   // follow suit with the rest of the functions
   hub.client.error = function (data) {
      alert(data);
   };

   // etc

</script>
```